# SQL:using vs on

Tags: sql, database, oracle

### Question

Let me give you the **description** of the tables used in the query

```
desc takes;
Name      Null     Type        
--------- -------- ----------- 
ID        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5) 
COURSE_ID NOT NULL VARCHAR2(8) 
SEC_ID    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(8) 
SEMESTER  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6) 
YEAR      NOT NULL NUMBER(4)   
GRADE              VARCHAR2(2) 
------------------------------------
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
desc course;
Name      Null     Type         
--------- -------- ----------------- 
COURSE_ID NOT NULL VARCHAR2(8)  
TITLE              VARCHAR2(50) 
DEPT_NAME          VARCHAR2(20) 
CREDITS            NUMBER(2)    
-------------------------------------
```

Query 1:

```
select course.COURSE_ID from course join takes on course.COURSE_ID=takes.COURSE_ID;
```

It is working fine.

But I have doubt on other query which is somehow related.

Query 2:

```
select course.COURSE_ID from course join takes using(COURSE_ID);
```

I am getting error as

> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 8
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier
>   25154. 00000 -  "column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier"
>   *Cause:    Columns that are used for a named-join (either a NATURAL join
>              or a join with a USING clause) cannot have an explicit qualifier.
>   *Action:   Remove the qualifier.

While if I change the attribute after select other than course.course_ID,like 
course.title as:

```
select course.title from course join takes using(COURSE_ID);
```

I am getting expected output, what there is error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says it all: when using `USING (COURSE_ID)` your rows don't contain `course.COURSE_ID`and `takes.COURSE_ID` anymore, but only a mere `COURSE_ID`.

This is invalid:

```
select course.COURSE_ID from course join takes using(COURSE_ID);
```

This is valid:

```
select COURSE_ID from course join takes using(COURSE_ID);
```

Comment: You are welcome. On a sidenote: I don't use `USING` very often, because of this very reason. When you have to add some subquery (e.g. an exists clause) you cannot qualify the column(s) in question. `USING` is, however, very useful with multiple full outer joins: `select col1, a.col2, b.col3, c.col4 from a full outer join b using(col1) full outer join c using(col1)`. This would look much more complicated with `ON` clauses.